# Find the sum of the series $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

The whole question looks like-

> Prove that, $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!+1}$ is convergent. Find its
>   value. (Options: $\pi/2$, $4\pi$, $\pi/4$, $2\pi$)

I have showed the convergence part. 
Let, $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n!+1}=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n a_n$.
Now, $a_n\ge0\ \forall n\in\Bbb{N}$, $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing sequence and converges to $0$. So, by alternative series test $\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n a_n$ is convergent.
But I can't find its value. If there is no factorial part beside $2n$ in the denominator, I can use power series representation of $\arctan(x)$ at $0$ to get its value.
Can anybody solve the problem? Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: Maybe the factorial sign is a typo? Since $\frac{\pi} {4}$ works perfectly without $! $ I can bet on that.

Comment: You mean $(2n)!$ or $2 \times n!$?

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 its $(2n)!$

Comment: @Zacky, I don't know, maybe typo in the book.

Comment: It cannot be that (taking into account the options).

Comment: Observe that $$\left |\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^n} {(2n)!+1)} \right | \leq \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {1} {(2n)!} = \frac {e+ \frac 1 e} {2} = \frac {e^2+1} {2e}= 1.543\ (\text {approx}.)$$

Comment: Since it is an alternating series w/ summands decreasing in magnitude, the sum will be sandwiched between successive terms of partial sums.  The partial sums are $\frac12, \frac16, \frac{31}{150},...$. This implies the limit falls inside $[\frac16, \frac{31}{150}]$ and none of your options can be the limit.

Comment: The only option which remains to be valid is $\frac {\pi} {4}.$ All other options are definitely false since they are all greater than $1.543.$

Comment: $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n)!+1}=0.20530423158998996966$

Comment: How did you calculate it?